# Ошибка в работе таймера с паузой

Tags: javascript

Приветствую. Столкнулся с проблемой в реализации таймера с паузой. Пауза не удаляет интервал, хотя должна.

http://jsfiddle.net/acqhr6y8/

```js
function Timer(callback, delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var countDownDate = start + delay;
  var timerId, start, remaining = delay;
  
  this.pause = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    remaining -= new Date() - start;
    clearInterval(this.cutdown);
  };

  this.resume = function() {
    start = new Date();
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    setInterval(this.cutdown, 1000);
  };

  this.cutdown = function() {
    remaining = remaining - 1000;
    minutes = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    seconds = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    (remaining < 0) ? clearInterval(this.cutdown) : $("#time").html(minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");
  };

  this.resume();
}
var timer = new Timer(function() {
  $("#status").html("Stoped");
}, 30000);
$("#pause").click(function() {
 timer.pause();
}); 
$("#resume").click(function() {
 timer.resume();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">
</div>
<div id="status">
  Up
</div>
<div id="pause">
  pause
</div>
<div id="resume">
  resume
</div>
```

Скорее всего напутал с интервалом, но не смог понять где.

Comment: `clearInterval` так же как и `clearTimeout` принимает id таймера. а ты ему передаешь функцию. В свою очередь, ты нигде не сохраняешь результат `setInterval(this.cutdown, 1000);` который и следовало бы передать в `clearInterval`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval), так же как и [`clearTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/cleartimeout), принимает *id таймера*.

В коде в вопросе ему передается **функция**.

В свою очередь, нигде не сохраняется результат `setInterval(this.cutdown, 1000);` который и следовало бы передать в [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval)

---

Для решения, нужно добавить дополнительную переменную, для хранения интервала и использовать ее аналогично имеющемуся `timerId`.

Кроме того, похоже логическая ошибка в методе `pause`. В нем не нужно менять `remaining` пытаясь связать с локальным временем, так как это состояние таймера и оно не должно меняться, пока таймер остановлен.

```js
function Timer(callback, delay) {
  var timerId, intervalId, start, remaining = delay;

  this.pause = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  };

  this.resume = function() {
    window.clearTimeout(timerId);
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    timerId = window.setTimeout(callback, remaining);
    intervalId = setInterval(this.cutdown, 1000);
  };

  this.cutdown = function() {
    remaining = remaining - 1000;
    minutes = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    seconds = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    (remaining < 0) ? clearInterval(intervalId): $("#time").html(minutes + "m " + seconds + "s");
  };

  this.resume();
}
var timer = new Timer(function() {
  $("#status").html("Stoped");
}, 30000);
$("#pause").click(function() {
  timer.pause();
});
$("#resume").click(function() {
  timer.resume();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="time">
</div>
<div id="status">
  Up
</div>
<div id="pause">
  pause
</div>
<div id="resume">
  resume
</div>
```

Comment: Вы не учли то что при нажатии на "resume" запускается таймер который уже не остановить "pause". так же можно по кнопке  "resume" можно запустить несколько таймеров и счётчик будет уменьшаться быстрее и скрипт уже вообще не остановится.. просто не будет отображать время <0

Comment: @Akubik, да, пропустил вызов `clearInterval`

Comment: вот теперь хорошо.

Comment: `... принимает id таймера. В коде в вопросе ему передается функция` — вот они, минусы динамической типизации.

Comment: @Arhad, я думаю тут проблема не в молотке :-)

Comment: ребят, любопытно, зачем 2 таймера? `setTimeout` можно вполне убрать, коллбэк напрямую, или вообще без него, так-то красавчик конечно, как заказчик попросил без лишних слов и разговоров ;-)

Comment: @Akubik, да, можно, но сейчас этот таймаут показывает конечное сообщение.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте такой синтаксис

```
var timerId = setTimeout(...);
clearTimeout(timerId);
```

дело в том что вам нужно разобраться с передачей параметров, временем и областью видимости переменных(как было указано выше)... я не знаю какая там у вас задача, но можно поступить проще, например таймер не останавливать, а менять переменную приращения - delta:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function Timer(callback, delay) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  var timerId, remaining = delay, delta =1000;
  
  this.pause = function() {
 $("#status").html("Paused");
 delta = 0;
  };
  this.resume = function() {
 $("#status").html("Up");
 delta = 1000;    
  };

  this.cutdown = function() {
    remaining = remaining - delta;
    minutes = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
    seconds = Math.floor((remaining % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
    $("#time").html(minutes + "m " + seconds + "s"); 
    if (remaining <= 0)  {clearInterval(timerId);callback();} 
  };
timerId = setInterval(this.cutdown, 1000);  
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="time">
</div>
<div id="status">
  Up
</div>
<div id="pause">
  pause
</div>
<div id="resume">
  resume
</div>
 
<script>
var timer = new Timer(function() {
$("#status").html("Stoped");
}, 30000);

$("#pause").click(function() {  
 timer.pause();
}); 
$("#resume").click(function() {
 timer.resume();
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

или нужно всё таки с запуском и остановкой таймеров работать? тогда в идеале нужно будет учесть еще время работы самого скрипта, загрузку браузера и их особенности